# PHP - search for value in file and echo the whole <div>

Tags: php

I have an external file with lots of informations e.g

```
http://domain.com/thefile.html
```

Each Data in the file is wrapped into a `<div>` element:

```
....
<div class="lineData">
  <div class="lineLData">Playstation</div>
  <div class="lineRData">awesome</div>
</div>
<div class="lineData">
  <div class="lineLData">xbox one</div>
  <div class="lineRData">not awesome</div>
</div>
<div class="lineData">
  <div class="lineLData">wii u</div>
  <div class="lineRData">mhhhh</div>
</div>
....
```

Now I want to search the whole file for the Keyword "Playstation" and echo the whole `<div>`:

```
<div class="lineData">
  <div class="lineLData">Playstation</div>
  <div class="lineRData">awesome</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with PHP ?

Comment: This may help you, I use it for my scraper scripts. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: So, it was not important to find <div>'s containing "playstation" after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume the resource / URL is `$url` :

```php
$result = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
```

find all `<div>`'s with the class `lineData` using DomXPath :

```php
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$lineDatas = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"lineData")]');
```

add all `lineData` `<div>`'s containing "playstation" to the `$result` array :

```php
foreach($lineDatas as $lineData) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($lineData->nodeValue), 'playstation') !== false) {
        $result[] = $lineData;
    }
}
```

example of outputting the result

```php
foreach($result as $lineData) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($lineData);
}
```

outputs

```html
<div class="lineData">
  <div class="lineLData">Playstation</div>
  <div class="lineRData">awesome</div>
</div>
```

when tested on the example HTML in OP.

Comment: mh your example seems to be better, but the code displays nothing and no error .. :( This is the code: http://laravel.io/bin/KkX4K

Comment: @user3633186 - because http://contenturl.com/content.html in your test code doesnt even exists - it is redirected and does not even then containing any lineData <div>'s. You should of course use the real URL instead, the one you want to scrape data from.

Comment: @user3633186, and of course there should be a <div> containing "playstation", which is not the case with your new link. But if you search for "farbe" or "Reaktionszeit" instead, it returns the expected result. Anyway, over and out.

Comment: arghhhh - i idiot :) of course i have to replace my search keyword. Now its working. Thanks so much sir !

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) for this purpose.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("file.html");
```

Now you can search for the div:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$res = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'lineData')]");
```

Now you have the div as [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domelement.php). Saving should be possible with these few lines:

```
$html = $res->ownerDocument->saveHTML($res);
```

Comment: The problem is each keyword is wrapped in a div with the same class. Can i load external .html files with loadHTMLFile ? In The PHP Doc there stands nothing about external files.

Comment: Or other way: Can i add an ID to each lineData class and THEN search for the div with the ID X ?

Comment: @user3633186: Use loadHTML with file_get_contents. You can add an ID with a foreach loop.

Comment: Interesting the `DomXPath` is initialised as `DOMXPath` assigned to the variable `$xpath`, later on referred to as `$finder` :)

Comment: @davidkonrad: Yes, I searched the XPath Query for class name on the Internet and failed to change this :-D